# Define event Dynamically in thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I create a thread and on it I create a DispatcherTimer.In this thread I define a method for Tick event but it never occurs.

```
class Net
{
    List<DispatcherTimer> Timers;
    Thread thread;

    Net()
    {
        thread = new Thread(method);
        Timers=new List<DispatcherTimer>();
        thread.Start();
    }

    void method()
    {
        while(true)
            if(condition)
            {
                Timers.Add(new DispatcherTimer());
                Timers[Timers.Count - 1] = new DispatcherTimer();
                Timers[Timers.Count - 1].Interval = new TimeSpan(2000000);
                Timers[Timers.Count - 1].Tick += new EventHandler(Timers_Tick);
                Timers[Timers.Count - 1].IsEnabled = true;
                Timers[Timers.Count - 1].Start();
            }
    }
    private void Timers_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some Code
    }
}
```

edit:Yes in my original code I start the thread.

Comment: You need to use `{` and `}` for a multiline while statement. Like this: while(condition) { // insert your code here }

Comment: You're running a busy wait loop in your `while (true) ...` statement. Please explain what you are trying to achieve, it's hard to understand from your code.

Comment: @jsve his code without braces is perfectly valid. It's only when you want the `while` loop applied to multiple statements, not multiple lines, that you need to use braces (`{}`) around your statements. Since in this case, it's applied to a single `if` statement (which itself is applied to a block of code), it's perfectly valid. Other questions, like whether his loop makes sense, or whether you might want to include the braces anyway for clarity, are separate.

Answer (score 0):

`DispatcherTimer` are meant to be `run on UI thread` but you are trying to create it from background thread whose Dispatcher is different from UI dispatcher.

So either you should pass UI dispatcher to the method and use that dispatcher for dispatcherTimer objects -

```
thread = new Thread(() => method(App.Current.Dispatcher));

void method(Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
   ....
   Timers.Add(new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Background, dispatcher));
   Timers[Timers.Count - 1] = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                                  dispatcher);
   ...
}
```

OR you should use [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).